# injected values in jersey test can not be loaded

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-test-framework

I'm running my application in tomee and trying to test my jax-rs web services via jersey test framework.

I added maven dependencies as below:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Inside my resource class i have

```
@Inject
private AuthenticationTokenService authenticationTokenService;
```

Inside my service class i have:

```
@Inject
private AuthenticationTokenIssuer tokenIssuer;

@Inject
private AuthenticationTokenParser tokenParser;
```

inside these two classes i have

```
@Inject
private AuthenticationTokenSettings settings;
```

I guess the my problem comes because of the member within `AuthenticationTokenSettings`

```
@Inject
@Config("token")
private String token;
```

these are injected with the qualifier @Config from a file via a Properties object.

I've written an InjectionResolver class to resolve

```
@Singleton
public static class ConfigInjectionResolver implements InjectionResolver<Configurable>
{
    private static Properties properties;

    public ConfigurableInjectionResolver()
    {
        properties = new Properties();
        InputStream stream = ConfigurationProducer.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");

        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find application.properties configuration file.");
        }

        try
        {
            this.properties.load(stream);
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Configuration file cannot be loaded.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> handle)
    {
        if (String.class == injectee.getRequiredType())
        {
            AnnotatedElement elem = injectee.getParent();
            if (elem instanceof Constructor)
            {
                Constructor ctor = (Constructor) elem;
                Configurable config = (Configurable) ctor.getParameterAnnotations()[injectee.getPosition()][0];
                return properties.get(config.value());
            }
            else
            {
                Configurable configurable = elem.getAnnotation(Configurable.class);
                return properties.get(configurable.value());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMethodParameterIndicator()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my overridden configure method i created the abstract binder like this.

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(
            AuthenticationResource.class);

    resourceConfig.register(new AbstractBinder()
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
            bind(AuthenticationTokenService.class).
                    to(AuthenticationResource.class);
            bind(AuthenticationTokenIssuer.class).
                    to(AuthenticationTokenService.class);
            bind(AuthenticationTokenParser.class).
                    to(AuthenticationTokenService.class);
            bind(AuthenticationTokenSettings.class).
                    to(AuthenticationTokenIssuer.class);
            bind(AuthenticationTokenSettings.class).
                    to(AuthenticationTokenParser.class);

            bind(ConfigurableInjectionResolver.class)
                    .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<Configurable>>()
                    {
                    })
                    .in(Singleton.class);

.
.
.
.
```

I have exception as below:

```
Apr 15, 2020 2:05:15 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenService] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenService class.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:168)
    .
    .
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenService
    contracts={com.transport.webservices.security.api.resource.AuthenticationResource}
    scope=org.glassfish.hk2.api.PerLookup
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@71a88a3e
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=142
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=1099971211
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:681)
    .
    .

WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenService] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenService class.
    .
    .
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenService
    contracts={com.transport.webservices.security.api.resource.AuthenticationResource}
    scope=org.glassfish.hk2.api.PerLookup
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@71a88a3e
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=142
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=1099971211
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:681)
    .
    .

WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=AuthenticationTokenSettings,parent=AuthenticationTokenIssuer,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,672817351)
    .
    .
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenIssuer errors were found
    .
    .
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenIssuer
    .
    .

WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 5
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=AuthenticationTokenSettings,parent=AuthenticationTokenIssuer,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,672817351)
    .
    .
MultiException stack 2 of 5
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenIssuer errors were found
    .
    .
MultiException stack 3 of 5
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.transport.webservices.security.service.AuthenticationTokenIssuer
    .
    .
MultiException stack 4 of 5
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.transport.webservices.security.api.resource.AuthenticationResource errors were found
    .
    .
MultiException stack 5 of 5
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.transport.webservices.security.api.resource.AuthenticationResource
    .
    .

java.lang.AssertionError: Should return status 200 expected:<200> but was:<500>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
```

In addition to this i had to add the below maven dependencies because my existing soap classes gave up compiling after i addded maven dependencies for jersey testing which i could not understand why.
I don't know i fthe problem is about this.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does it work while running the app?

Comment: Also, why `TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<Configurable>>`? Shouldnt it be Config? Thats your annotation

Comment: It's running on tomee and for the second question it's a typo sorry for that. I tried with field injection and constructor injection but i still couldn't make it work properly on jersey test.

Comment: When i converted it to ctr. injection and bound as ```AuthenticationTokenService authenticationTokenService
                        = new AuthenticationTokenService(
 Long.valueOf(properties.getProperty("authentication.jwt.validFor")),
 Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("authentication.jwt.refreshLimit")),
                                new AuthenticationTokenIssuer(authenticationTokenSettings),
                                new AuthenticationTokenParser(authenticationTokenSettings));
                bind(authenticationTokenService).
to(AuthenticationTokenService.class);```

Comment: But the solution above does not look like the best practice and in addition as i stated in my original question the app does not work this way. I'm not sure if it's about dependencies? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is the way i'm thinking wron about jersey testing. What i wan t to achieve is to tell the runtime where to find the injected values(in this case i should not need to have constructor injections in my way of thinking) and for the qualifier injected values i want to create a ```InjectionResolver``` to tell the runtime where to find the primitive member values and strings (in this case a properties txt file)

Comment: One more thing i converted some of my private injected classes to public for binding. Any method to use private injected classes for testing?

Comment: Why don't you create a `Feature` where you do all the configuration for the auth services. That way you don't have to do the same thing in the test again. Just register the Feature. Other than that, there is not enough information to help you solve your problem. You have so many services that are involved with the injection, and you are not showing any of them.

Comment: Actually i took the jax-rs authentication implementation of @cassiomolin as a best practice and trying to create an integration test for that implementation which he shared here https://github.com/cassiomolin/jersey-jwt to see if it's going to fit my requirements. The github project includes tests with arquillian but i'm trying to create integration with jersey framework. And i'm looking for how to create ```Feature``` in jersey testing framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a class extending `AnnotationLiteral` as below:

```
public static class ConfigurableQualifierLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<Configurable> implements Configurable
{
    String value;

    ConfigurableQualifierLiteral(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String value()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then in my `AbstractBinder` i've bound my annotated members as below:

```
bind(Long.valueOf(36000)).to(new TypeLiteral<Long>()
            {
            }).qualifiedBy(new TestAuthenticationResource.ConfigurableQualifierLiteral("authentication.jwt.validFor"));
```